# Fallo con DCont en Access

Tags: ms-access

Estoy haciendo una consulta en Access utilizando la siguiente expresión:

DCont("[PN]";"[MAT_Consulta3]";"[Orden] = '" & [Orden] & " Y [Estado Material] = 'Falta Real'")

Tengo dos tablas, una con un listado de órdenes de producción y otra con los materiales que demandan dichas órdenes. Lo que quiero hacer es una consulta contando los materiales en falta real para cada orden de la primera tabla. La fórmula parece que está bien redactada pero me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no hubiera ningún material en "Falta real" debería dar 0, no?? Qué estoy haciendo mal??
Gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Si miras, verás que 8267502 tiene un apóstrofe al principio, pero no al final, con lo cual creo que Access está interpretando que `[Orden]` debe ser igual al texto `8267502 Y [Estado material] = `. Mira bien los apóstrofes a ver si es eso.